# Error installing visibility analysis plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed, visibility

When I try to download and install the latest version of the visibility analysis plugin from both https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/ and http://www.zoran-cuckovic.from.hr/QGIS-visibility-analysis/ on either a PC running QGIS 3.2.3 or a Mac running 3.6.1 I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'QGIS-visibility-analysis-master' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'viewshedanalysis' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/[USER]/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/QGIS-visibility-analysis-master/__init__.py", line 52, in classFactory
    from viewshedanalysis import ViewshedAnalysis
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'viewshedanalysis'
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is no point to install the new version of Viewshed plugin since it is available as the boult-in plugin in the QGIS 3x.

You can find it in the processing toolbox on your right. Type in the search bar "Visibility analysis" and you will get all the options available.

[image]